# CredRead() not working across login sessions

Tags: c#, security, credentials, credential-manager

I am using the Credential Manager API as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435561/encrypting-credentials-in-a-wpf-application). Quoting relevant code snippet:

```
public static Credential ReadCredential(string applicationName)
{
    IntPtr nCredPtr;
    bool read = CredRead(applicationName, CredentialType.Generic, 0, out nCredPtr);
    if (read)
    {
        using (CriticalCredentialHandle critCred = new CriticalCredentialHandle(nCredPtr))
        {
            CREDENTIAL cred = critCred.GetCredential();
            return ReadCredential(cred);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

It works great, except that when I log off my Windows account and then login again, CredRead() returns false and `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` gives me `1168`, or `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`.

Why this behaviour? Does the Credential Management API work only for the current session, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**: A comment beneath [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678393/why-does-win32-api-function-credenumerate-return-error-not-found-if-im-impers) says that:

> The documents for the credential management APIs seem to indicate that these credentials are associated with a logon session. Perhaps LogonUser results in a new logon session, so the credentials don't exist there.

However I haven't yet found any evidence that Credential Management is session-specific. I think it would be pretty useless if that were the case.

**Edit 2**: Just for the record, if you need to get the error number indicating why CredRead() is failing, check ReadCred() method in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peerchan/archive/2005/11/01/487834.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure how the credential is persisted by setting the `Persist` property

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374788(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
CRED_PERSIST_SESSION
CRED_PERSIST_LOCAL_MACHINE
CRED_PERSIST_ENTERPRISE
```